# Spree customize/extend user roles and permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying to specify some custom roles in Spree for example role 'client' and extend the permissions to access the admin section for this role.

This user will be able to access only those Product created by that user. Concept is letting a user with role 'client' manage only products and other certain Models.

To start with I added CanCan plugin and defined a RoleAbility Class in role_ability.rb

Just following this post : [Spree Custom Roles Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455174/spree-custom-roles-permissions)

```
class RoleAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.has_role? 'admin'
        can :manage, :all
    elsif user.has_role? 'client_admin'
      can :read, Product
      can :admin, Product
    end
  end
end
```

Added this to an initializer : config/initializers/spree.rb

```
Ability.register_ability(RetailerAbility)
```

Also extended admin_products_controller_decorator.rb :app/controllersadmin_products_controller_decorator.rb

```
Admin::ProductsController.class_eval do
    def authorize_admin
        authorize! :admin, Product
        authorize! params[:action].to_sym, Product
    end
end
```

But I am getting flash message 'Authorisation Failure'

Trying to find some luck, I referred following links

A github gist for Customizing Spree Roles : https://gist.github.com/1277326

Here's a similar issue what I am facing : http://groups.google.com/group/spree-user/browse_thread/thread/1e819e10410d03c5/23b269e09c7ed47e

All efforts in vain...

Any pointers highly appreciated ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using spree 1.1.1, spree_multi_domain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found it.

After doing some careful research found that spree 1.1.1 had changed the classes by adding "Spree" module to every class, this resulted in url like "spree/admin/overview" which earlier was "admin/overview".

So that worked for me and I was able to control the Permissions for my roles.